# concatenate a string that contains backquote characters R

Tags: r

I have a string that contains back quotes, which mess up the concatenate function. If you try to concatenate with back ticks, the concatenate function doesn't like this:

```
a <- c(`table`, `chair`, `desk`)
Error: object 'chair' not found
```

So I can create the variable:

```
bad.string <- "`table`, `chair`, `desk`"
a <- gsub("`", "", bad.string)
```

That gives a string `"table, chair, desk".`

It then should be like:

```
good.object <- c("table", "chair", "couch", "lamp", "stool")
```

I don't know why the backquotes cause the concatenate function to break, but how can I replace the string to not have the illegal characters?

Comment: Please show your actual vector with `dput(object)`; clearly it's not `c(\`table\`, \`chair\`, \`desk\`)` because that produces an error.

Comment: If you have a string that contains backquotes, how did you read it?  Whether that object was created or not.

Comment: It literally is an object pasted from MySql that is 100 items long of the form `a`, `b`, `c`, ... Ideally I'd have an SQL query to select all table names but for now I have to paste table names into a string and gsub the backticks out. I have to do this for lots of tables so I don't want to manually find/replace the backticks.

Comment: Uhh, how does `"\`table\`, \`chair\`, \`desk\`"` become `c("table", "chair", "couch", "lamp", "stool")`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
good.string <- trimws(unlist(strsplit(gsub("`", "", bad.string), ",")))
```

Here `gsub()` is used to remove the backticks, `strsplit` converts a single string into a list of strings, where the comma in the original string denotes the separation, `unlist()` converts the list of strings into a vector of strings and `trimws()` deletes trailing or leading whitespaces.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation on [quotes](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Quotes.html), back ticks are reserved for non-standard variable names such as

```
`the dog` <- 1:5
`the dog`
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

So when you are trying to use concatenate, R is doing nothing wrong. It looks at all the variable in `c()` and tries to find them, causing the error.

If this is a vector you wrote, just copy replace all of the backticks with single or double quotes.

If this is somehow being generated in R, bring the entire thing out as a string, then use `gsub()` and `eval(parse())`

```
eval(parse(text = gsub('\`',"\'","c(`table`, `chair`, `desk`)")))
[1] "table" "chair" "desk"
```

EDIT: For the new example of `bad.string`

You have to go through, replace all of the back ticks with double quotes, then you can read it through `read.csv()`. This is a little janky though as it gives back a row vector, so we transpose it to get back a column vector

```
bad_string <- "`table`, `chair`, `desk`"
okay_string <- gsub('\`','\"',bad.string)

okay_string
# [1] "\"table\", \"chair\", \"desk\""
t(read.csv(text = okay_string,header=FALSE, strip.white = TRUE))
#       [,1]   
# V1 "table"
# V2 "chair"
# V3 "desk"
```

Comment: Also note that the string doesn't contain backquotes because you never actually created a string.  Something like "`chair`" would be a string that contains backquotes and wouldn't cause any issues.

Comment: @dason yes that is correct, you can have backquotes, but it's also kosher to escape them s.t. `"\`chair\`"`